# How to reproduce a tab bar view like in Server application?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I'm looking to replicate something similar to the tab view of the new Server application, like this:

[image: server]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/74e44898d9a8a37cdfce17a8740d5fef.png))</sub>

but I'm not finding any style setting in IB that can achieve this.

My target is 10.9, is this a total custom view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is custom control, but you can reproduce this behaviour and appearance in a different ways: with `NSSegmentedControl` or `NSButton` for example.

Also you can have a look on my custom [DOTabbar](https://github.com/stel/DOTabbar) and usage example.